# Creating a dashboard using an excel as database?

Tags: excel, vba, automation

So Basically we have a data being written into an excelSheet (.xls file excel 2003) every 30 seconds from four machines Basically data Being MAchine #, Entry #, StartTime, EndTime , Operator, job Done Etc.

Now my client want to create A dashboard Like Screen with four column representing four machines and Last ten entries of each machine say Entry # being displayed beneath each Corresponding Machine using the excel file as database & dashboard being refreshed every one minute or less.

Clicking on any Entry # will print the details of that job from data base and will then return back to dashboard.

Did any one has any ideas how this could be done?

Preferably if this could be done using VBA?

If not, then what are the options?

Comment: You can use an excel sheet as a table in ADO as long as there are column headings. Alternatively you could use vba to find the bottom row of each sheet and extract from that row to row-9

Comment: say i get the last 10 entries of the each machine using VBA. but what about the refreshing part. how to refresh the data to show the the latest data. even the excel (database file) is updating every 30 seconds. this which i couldn't understand?

Comment: There is an On_Timer event that you can use to automatically run code at a given time - if the routine resets the timer you can get it to run every 30 secs